# Show blank or null values in my SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

I'm a newbie to `SSRS Reporting Services`. My report runs great except that it doesn't show `null` or `blank` cells.  I know there are some.  What should I add to this query to show the `blank` or `null` in the `DistributionOwnerId`?  Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT Id,
CONVERT(varchar(10), DistributionDate, 101) AS DistributionDate,
DistributionDate AS OriginalDistributionDate, 
MedDrugName AS DrugName,
MedDistributionSessionDescription AS Session,
DistributionOwnerId,
CASE a.[Status] 
    WHEN 0 THEN 'Success' 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Refused By Inmate' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Inmate Did Not Show' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Inmate Not In Cell' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Security Lockdown'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Medication Held (State Reason)' 
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Medication Out Of Stock' 
END AS Status, 
Notes, 
UserName,
(SELECT     NoteText + ';' AS Expr1
    FROM          MARDistAddNotes AS c
    WHERE      (a.Id = MARDistributionId) FOR XML PATH('')
) AS AdditionalNotes
, InmateLastName
, InmateFirstName
, InmateNumber
FROM         MARDistribution AS a
WHERE     (Status > 0)
ORDER BY DistributionDate, Session
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE()) 'Date Part Only'
```

[image]

Comment: Generally, if you want to do that, you can check in expression and then display the value as a string by yourself. like `=iif(field=nothing,"Null",field)`. Can you paste picture showing what you are getting and what you want?

Comment: I tried, but it wouldn't let me paste.  In the column DistributionOwnerID it needs to show blank when there are no initials.  I'd actually love for it to show red when there aren't any, but I'll be thrilled just to have it be blank.

Comment: Sharing a picture of SQL outcome and report output will make life easy.

Comment: I added a pic of what I need to see. I hope that helps.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Still confused. normally if there is no data, the corresponding cell will be empty. I'm sorry but ..... ok...can you share the result of your query? thanks.

Comment: That is the result of my query.  :)  I just clipped a couple lines, but they are all like that.  I know that there are blanks, but they don't show up in the query.